# How can I get images in XAML to display as their actual size?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, image

I have a **27 x 27** pixel image that I am displaying in WPF but it displays **larger** than the size of the **window**.

**How can I get it to display its actual size?**

[alt text http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/m20dk6.png](http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/m20dk6.png)

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestImage23434.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel x:Name="MainStackPanel"/>
</Window>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System;

namespace TestImage23434
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
            tb.Text = "above image ";
            MainStackPanel.Children.Add(tb);

            Image img = new Image();
            img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\test\circle.png"));
            img.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            img.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
            MainStackPanel.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            MainStackPanel.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
            MainStackPanel.Children.Add(img);

            TextBlock tb2 = new TextBlock();
            tb2.Text = "below image";
            MainStackPanel.Children.Add(tb2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF: How to display an image at its original size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055550/wpf-how-to-display-an-image-at-its-original-size)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`img.Stretch = Stretch.None`

By default, the [Stretch property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.stretch.aspx) has a value of `Uniform`, which resizes the image to fill all available space.

Comment: I don't think I've ever used an image in such a way I've had to USE the Stretch property... I forgot it even existed.

Comment: if we Set "img.Stretch = Stretch.None" there is problem when  the image is too large some portion of image is not get visible.Any solution for this

Answer (score 8):

None of these tips were working for me. Some binding tricks is what got me going.

```
<Image Source="yourPic.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"
Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Source.PixelWidth}"
Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Source.PixelHeight}" />
```

You could probably set Strech to None but this worked for my app using .net 4.5.1.

Comment: Binding the width and height works well in combination with a static `MaxWidth` and `MaxHeight` and `Stretch="Uniform"` in order to have original size up to some limit. The accepted answer shows only part of the image in such a scenario.

Comment: You can't have `Stretch="None"` if you want this to work! I lost almost an hour before I realized it.

Answer (score 2):

```
img.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
img.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
img.Stretch = Stretch.None;
```

The StackPanel will stretch to fill/overflow whatever container it's in unless its size is specified. Since you aren't setting margins or alignments on anything, the default behavior for everything is `Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"`, or simply put "Stretch to fill". Aligning/positioning your elements will fix this issue.

EDIT: Added `img.Stretch = Stretch.None;`, also I built a sample app and tested it... it works.

Comment: How does the alignment affect the size of the displayed image?

Comment: The standard alignment is `Stretch`, which *does* affect the size.

Comment: I tried that but it still expands to the size of its possible area. I tried putting these settings on the StackPanel as well but it still expands.

Comment: @Heinzi - Thx, was wondering why it got a downvote until I saw your edit... :D

Answer (score 2):

It could also be your image's DPI property in its metadata. It should be 96.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4965404/659326