# WPF: How to display an image at its original size?

Tags: wpf, image, resize, size

I have a problem with displaying images in WPF.

Here's my code:

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Margin="0,5">
        <Button.Content>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,0">
                <Image Source="/images/user_add.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="24" Height="24" />
                <TextBlock Text="添加" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
```

I have an image with original size 32*32, but when I ran the above code, the image will stretch to fill all the space, beyond its original size. I also set the "Stretch" property to "None", but it seems that it doesn't work.

So, how can I fix this problem?
Thank you!

Comment: Verify the image DPI by displaying the following columns in the _Windows File Explorer_: `Horizontal Resolution` and `Vertical Resolution`.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841511/how-can-i-get-images-in-xaml-to-display-as-their-actual-size) is a similar question. Generally setting `Stretch="None"` is enough.

**It is also very important what DPI has the image set in metadata.** It took me quite a while before figuring out that if the image's DPI is different from the monitor's DPI (usually 96), [WPF will automatically resize the image, as it tries to be DPI-independent](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2007/10/05/blurry-bitmaps.aspx).

---

**EDIT**

The MSDN link is broken, here is the new link:
[MSDN Blog - Blurry Bitmaps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dwayneneed/blurry-bitmaps). Let's keep the old link around to be used for archive.org, in case the new link stops working also.

Comment: Great tip regarding DPI settings, Paja. Several of my toolbar icons had been set to 72 DPI, which causes them to appear larger even if the pixel dimensions are 16x16.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying WPF will layout your window differently depending on the resolution of the screen? There's no way that could possibly be a good thing.

Comment: @KyleDelaney Have you read the article I linked in the answer?

Comment: Yes, and I'm asking for clarification on it.

Comment: @KyleDelaney Yes, WPF takes into account the DPI of your screen when rendering. Your controls and images will have (almost) the same physical size on different monitors with different DPIs. It's actually a good thing, otherwise your controls on a 300 DPI monitor would be tiny and text barely readable. It's the correct way to handle the issue of supporting screens with vastly different DPIs, and the same approach is used on smart phones.

Comment: So it's not just images but all controls? So the entire application gets scaled rather than just the images, and the relative sizes and the layout get preserved?

Comment: @KyleDelaney Yes, that's also why you use "points" instead of "pixels" to specify sizes, distances, margins etc in WPF.

Comment: So, how to tell WPF to ignore the DPI and display image pixel to pixel? I think the link is broken

Comment: @PawełAudionysos I have fixed the broken link

Answer (score 7):

Try not specifying width or height, use it like this instead:

```
<Image Source="/images/user_add.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

Answer (score 7):

```
<Image Source="Images/Background.png" UseLayoutRounding="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Width="600" Height="800" Stretch="Fill" />
```

This one works for me, for an image with `600x800 pixels` and `96dpi`.

@rishad2m8 If size is unknown one can detect the size first with https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.size(v=vs.110).aspx I'd guess.

Comment: what if image size is unknown?

Comment: You're a saviour. You wouldn't want to know how long I was agonising over this issue.

Comment: UseLayoutRounding set to true worked for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Adding to Paya's answer: to compensate `WPF`'s attempt to adapt to the monitors resolution you should be able to set the `Width` and `Height` to the file's original dimensions and use `Stretch="Fill"`. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the image with original size, but don't know the image size, I think the best way is to set the image as background of UIElement. Like this:

```
    <Button Height="100" Width="100">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/images/user_add.png" Stretch="None"/>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
```