# Two images with the same dimensions are sizing differently

Tags: c#, wpf, image, stretch

I have two versions of the same image, which I want to display in a WPF application.
For me, they have the same properties, but in the application with a control "Image", with a stretch to none, they are displayed differently.

I would understand why.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

[The two image files](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33091854/Image%20files.zip)

Comment: I can't download your zip file where I am. What are the DPI settings for the images - are they the same? Also, share your xaml.

Comment: May not be relevant - see [this social.msdn thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/513cc286-ad22-4045-b992-6334bf48c6ea/bitmap-resolution).

Comment: See this thread [WPF: How to display an image at its original size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055550/wpf-how-to-display-an-image-at-its-original-size) Your first image is 96 DPI, the second - 72 DPI

Comment: Indeed it's because of that. The images has been edited with PhotoFiltre, which changes automatically the DPI.
Thank you !